# Show text when matching visitors city with GEOIP

Tags: javascript, geolocation, ip, geoip, city

Hey im using this code to get location information from visitors...

```html
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<br>Country Code:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_country_code());</script>
<br>Country Name:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_country_name());</script>
<br>City:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>
<br>Region:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region());</script>
<br>Region Name:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region_name());</script>
<br>Latitude:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_latitude());</script>
<br>Longitude:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_longitude());</script>
<br>Postal Code:
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_postal_code());</script>
```

How can i make it show an text or picture if document.write(geoip_city()); match my city? If im an visitor from new york, then it will show an flag or text?

**EDIT**
I tried something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (geoip_city() === "New York") {
<img src='/uploads/2013/10/446771808704305.jpg?width=226'>
} else {
<img src='/uploads/2013/10/446771562037663.jpg?width=226'
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>
<br>
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region_name());</script>
```

I didn't get any pictures, do you maybe know where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (geoip_city() === "New York") {
  // Display your image for New York
  document.write("<img src='new-york.png'>");
} else {
  // Display the other image
  document.write("<img src='other.png'>");
}
</script>
```

The geoip library from maxmind seems to be a [legacy library](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/) and you'll have to purchase a plan to use the API.

Comment: If you want an alternative, I wrote a similar library: [userinfo.io](http://userinfo.io) that is based on MaxMind database.